# rest framework Serializer

Tags: django, serialize, django-rest-framework

Добрый день!
Описываю api переписки между пользователями.

Создаю новое сообщение, записываю текст сообщения, в качестве отправителя указывается текущий авторизованный пользователь. Так же принимаю юзера чтобы найти нужную переписку или создать новую.
Но модельска **Message** не содержит поля **recipient**, поэтому я ловлю ошибку. Как мне это обойти?

```
class CreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    content = serializers.CharField()
    recipient = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    thread = None

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        message = Message.objects.create(
            thread=self.thread,
            sender=user,
            content=validated_data['content']
        )

        self.thread.userthread_set.exclude(user=user).update(deleted=False, unread=True)
        self.thread.userthread_set.filter(user=user).update(deleted=False, unread=False)
        return message

    def validate_recipient(self, recipient):
        sender = self.context['request'].user

        if sender == recipient:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Вы не можете писать самому себе.')

        thread = Thread.objects.filter(Q(userthread__user=sender) and Q(userthread__user=recipient)).first()
        # создаем переписку если ее нету
        if not thread:
            thread = Thread.objects.create()
            self.thread.userthread_set.create(user=recipient, deleted=False, unread=True)
            self.thread.userthread_set.create(user=sender, deleted=True, unread=False)

        self.thread = thread

        return recipient
```

> AttributeError at /api/v1/messages/create/
>   'Message' object has no attribute 'recipient'

Вот модельки описывающие переписку, как такового понятия отправитель - получатель нету, есть отправитель сообщения, и подписчики на переписку

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through="UserThread")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {}".format(
            self.subject,
            ", ".join([str(user) for user in self.users.all()])
        )    

class UserThread(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    unread = models.BooleanField()
    deleted = models.BooleanField()   

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, related_name="messages")
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="sent_messages")
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("sent_at",)
```

Comment: Ну если это переписка между пользователями,как она может быть без получателя? Покажите модель.